# Modify of AES S-Box

Tags: cryptography, aes

Is there any way to change standart S-Box and Inv. S-Box of AES algorithm with another pair of S And Inv S -boxes?
Standard S-Box and inv. S-Box here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box

Comment: You can certainly create any number of custom S-boxes, but 1) you need to specify the crypto library (or at least a programming language) where you want to use custom S-box 2) you should be aware that with the very high probability any S-box that you will create will be insecure.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I have my own aes program in C++, where i'm trying to change s-box with another one, but it don't work with another tables, only with standart s-box. Don't know why

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible explanation is that your sBoxInv is not the inverse of sBox. A simple check reveals that sBox[5e] = 6a, whereas sBoxInv[6a] = 68 (and not 5e as it should be).

Comment: Ye, didn't see it. Will check out for similar mistakes.. Thx.

Comment: sBox[5e] = 6a and sBox[68] = 6a. As I know all values should be uniq.